# Javascript: Default prototype fields showing undefined for object created using null constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor, prototype

I am noticing some behaviour in the code below that I can't explain.  I'm hoping that someone can enlighten me about why this is happening.

The code example below is available on JSFiddle as well if that's easier to read.
https://jsfiddle.net/0b5rh4cg/

**Code:**

```
function Book() {

};

function Book (title, author) {
    this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
};

Book.prototype = {
    title: "",
  ISBN: "isbn",
  length: 100,
  genre: "genre",
  covering: "covering",
  author: "author",
  currentPage: 0,

  toString: function toString() {
    console.log("toString Function");
    console.log('Title: ' + this.title + '\n' +
                            'ISBN: ' + this.ISBN + '\n' + 
                            'length: ' + this.length + '\n' + 
                'genre: ' + this.genre + '\n' + 
                'covering: ' + this.covering + '\n' + 
                'author: ' + this.author + '\n' + 
                'currentPage: ' + this.currentPage + '\n');
  }
};

var book1 = new Book();
book1.toString();

var book2 = new Book("First edition", "Random");
book2.toString();
```

**Output of book1.toString()**
toString Function 
*Title: undefined* 
ISBN: isbn 
length: 100 
genre: genre 
covering: covering 
*author: undefined* 
currentPage: 0

**Output of book2.toString()**
toString Function
*Title: First edition*
ISBN: isbn
length: 100
genre: genre
covering: covering
*author: Random*
currentPage: 0

My confusion surrounds the author and title fields.  In the null constructor, these fields default to "undefined" instead of the ones set out in the prototype for the Book class.

Thanks to anyone who helps with this.

Cheers, Cam.

Comment: JS doesn't support parameter polymorphism, the second `book` overwrites the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaScript` is not like `Java` (or other programming languages) where you can have methods with the same name or multiple constructors if they have different number or type of parameters. In this case, you've replaced `Book()` with `Book(title, author)`

To achieve what you want, you can do something like this:

```
function Book (title, author) {
    this.title = title||"";
    this.author = author||"";
};
```

In this case, `title` and `author` will default to an empty `String`.

Or something like this:

```
function Book (title, author) {
    this.title = title && author ? title : "";
    this.author = title && author ? author : "";
};
```

Comment: I see what your saying, Titus.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Properties you define in function constructor will always override the ones defined on the prototype.

Whe the JavaScript engine is providing a prototype value it will first look it up (hasOwnProperty) on the instance, than on it's prototype chain.

Because you implicitly declared title and author in the function constructor, the **new** operator crated the object with these two properties on it's instance space so the object looks like this:

Books {
   title:undefined,
   auto:undefined,
   **proto**:{
       title: "",
       ISBN: "isbn",
       length: 100,
       genre: "genre",
       covering: "covering",
       author: "author",
       currentPage: 0,
       **proto**: Object
   }
}

So when the property is first ask the JavaScript engine will return the ones on the instance that were initialized as undefined, because no arguments where passed when created with **new**.

Comment: This is really great information.  Thanks @fistuks!

Comment: Most welcome, for further knowledge i suggest you read aout the prototype chain on the MDN: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1):

In your initial **Book** function

```
function Book (title, author) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
};
```

you are passing in nothing, so the parameter enters the function with a **value** of undefined. Since you are declaring both **title** and **author** you are still assigning a value to both of them, which in this case is **undefined**.

The first lookup on the **Book** object hits your declared properties which both have a value, so you get the returned values of **undefined**. Since there is a value for both of these properties of **Book** the lookup stops and does not propagate up the prototype chain as you are most likely expecting.

If you would like to set default values when you are **not** passing in parameters to the called function, then just add this to your function.

```
function Book (title, author) {
  this.title = title || "";
  this.author = author || "author";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for filling in the remaining pieces of the puzzle @SoEzpZ.  This answer with the other two provides a very detailed and complete answer to the original question.